# Canvas element is getting removed from the page

Tags: 8, page-controller

I am new to Drupal 8. I am trying to implement Chart js in Drupal 8.

I am trying to create a  element to load the chart. But while rendering the page,  element is getting removed automatically. 
Below the controller code.

```
class DashboardController extends ControllerBase {

  public function content() {

    return array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup'   =>  '<div class="chart"><canvas id="test"></canvas></div>',
    );
  }
}
```

Here, I am getting only `<div class="chart"></div>`

I am unable to find the canvas in the page. Because of that, chart is not getting loaded.

Anyone help me to figure out the exact problem.

Comment: Use type inline_template instead of markup.

Comment: Or you could implement hook_theme and make your own template so you don't have to use the inline_template workaround.